# How to automatically place number of occurrences of a certain command inside xparse environment at every occurence of that command?

Tags: macros, environments, expl3, latex3, xparse

There is an (xparse) environment `\myEnv`, and there is unspecified number of `\myCo` commands provided by the user inside that environment. I need to write a code for the environment which would count the number of `\myCo` occurrences and would display that number at each `\myCo` occurrence.

```
\documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}

\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage{xparse}

\def\myCo{}

\begin{document}
  \ExplSyntaxOn
    \NewDocumentEnvironment{myEnv}{+b}
      { #1 % before displaying the contents,
           %  I need to count how many \myCo
           %   occurrences there are and display this number
           %    at each occurrence of \myCo
      } {}
  \ExplSyntaxOff
  \begin{myEnv}
    \myCo This is sentence 1. This is sentence 2.\myCo This is sentence 3.\myCo This is sentence 4. This is sentence 5. This is sentence 6.\myCo
  \end{myEnv}
\end{document}
```

I would expect the output to look something like this:
(4) This is sentence 1. This is sentence 2.(4) This is sentence 3.(4) This is sentence 4. This is sentence 5. This is sentence 6.(4)

where (4) is the number of `\myCo` commands.

Comment: Do you have control over `\myCo`?  If so, you could just put a counter inside the macro that counts its own invocations.

Comment: Can `myEnv`s that contain `\myCo`s be nested?  How to treat, e.g., `\begin{myEnv}\myCo ... \myCo ... \begin{myEnv}\myCo ... \myCo\end{myEnv}... \myCo...\end{myEnv}` ?

Comment: @HenriMenke That wouldn't quite work as the OP wants the *total* count rather than an incremental count. You could instead add a counter and at the end of the document save the counter to the aux file and then print the final total from the aux file using a `\ref{...}`erence. If you want the total count inside an environment that appears in different parts of the document then it is trickier to make this idea fly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For both of these things you can use [LaTeX3](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/expl3) regular expressions. To count the number of occurrences of `\myCo` you can use `\regex_count:nnN` and then you can use `\regex_replace_all:nnN` to insert the count after each instance of the command. The regular expression match for the control sequence `\myCo` is `\c{myCo}` so to find the number of occurrences you would use something like:

```
\regex_count:nnN {\c{myCo}} {#1} \l_tmpa_int
```

and the `\regex_replace_all:nnN` command is similar. With this in place the output produced by your MWE is the expected:

[image]

Here is the full code.

```
\documentclass[varwidth, border=10mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage{xparse}

\def\myCo{}

\begin{document}
  \ExplSyntaxOn
    \int_new:N \l_myCo_int
    \tl_new:N \l_myenv_tl
    \NewDocumentEnvironment{myEnv}{+b}
      {
      \regex_count:nnN {\c{myCo}} {#1} \l_myCo_int
      \tl_set:Nn \l_myenv_tl {#1}
      \regex_replace_all:nnN {\c{myCo}} 
         {\c{myCo}~(\c{int_use:N} \c{l_myCo_int})} \l_myenv_tl
      \tl_use:N \l_myenv_tl
      } {}
  \ExplSyntaxOff
  \begin{myEnv}
    \myCo This is sentence 1. This is sentence 2.\myCo 
    This is sentence 3.\myCo This is sentence 4. 
    This is sentence 5. This is sentence 6.\myCo
  \end{myEnv}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you need counting the single instances of `\myCo` separately for each instance and each nesting level of the `myEnv` environment, you can achieve that by defining `myEnv` and `\myCo` in a way where you have LaTeX both count instances of the `myEnv`-environment and count instances of the `\myCo`-macro and where a `\label` command for retrieving the value of the last `\myCo` is issued at the end of the `myEnv` environment.

If you have LaTeX count the `\myCo`s in terms of `\refstepcounter`, you can place `\label` commands behind them for referencing.

I implemented things in a way where you can do with or without the **hyperref** package.

When loading **hyperref**, referencing without creation of a hyperlink is availabvle via `\ref*`.
But that "starred" referencing command is not available when doing without **hyperref**.
Therefore I used the **refcount** package for implementing a referencing command without creation of a hyperlink.
This command will be available no matter if **hyperref** is loaded or is not loaded.

As internally `\label..\ref`/`\getrefbykeydefault` is used, you need to compile the example at least twice/until the warnings
`LaTeX Warning: There were undefined references.` and
`LaTeX Warning: Label(s) may have changed. Rerun to get cross-references right`
do not occur in the console/in the log file any more .

```
\documentclass{article}

%\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{refcount}
\usepackage{xspace}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\nolinkref[1]{%
  \IfRefUndefinedBabel{#1}{%
    \refused{#1}%
    \nfss@text {\reset@font \bfseries ??}%
  }{%
    \getrefbykeydefault{#1}{}{0}%
  }%
}%

\newcounter{myEnvCtr}
\newcounter{myCoCtr}[myEnvCtr]
\def\theHmyEnvCtr{\arabic{myEnvCtr}}
\def\theHmyCoCtr{myEnvInstance\myEnv@THISmyEnvCtr.\arabic{myCoCtr}}
\def\themyCoCtr{\arabic{myCoCtr}}

\newcommand\myEnv@SAVEDcurrentlabel{}
\newcommand\myEnv@SAVEDcurrentHref{}
\newcommand\myEnv@SAVEDcurrentlabelname{}
\newcommand\myEnv@SAVEDmyCoCtr{}
\newcommand\myEnv@THISmyEnvCtr{0}

\newcommand\myCo{%
  \refstepcounter{myCoCtr}%
  % Save the referencing-data from the last \myCo:
  \let\myEnv@SAVEDcurrentlabel=\@currentlabel
  \let\myEnv@SAVEDcurrentHref=\@currentHref
  \let\myEnv@SAVEDcurrentlabelname=\@currentlabelname
  % In case of using zref-package or the like you may need
  % to add the saving of the values of some more
  % referencing-properties here.
  (\nolinkref{myEnvInstance.\myEnv@THISmyEnvCtr.LastmyCo})\xspace%
}%
\newenvironment{myEnv}{%
  \edef\myEnv@SAVEDmyCoCtr{\number\value{myCoCtr}}%
  \stepcounter{myEnvCtr}%
  \edef\myEnv@THISmyEnvCtr{\number\value{myEnvCtr}}%
}{%
  \ifnum\number\value{myCoCtr}>0 %
    \begingroup
      % Restore the referencing-data from the last \myCo:
      \let\@currentlabel=\myEnv@SAVEDcurrentlabel
      \let\@currentHref=\myEnv@SAVEDcurrentHref
      \let\@currentlabelname=\myEnv@SAVEDcurrentlabelname
      % In case of using zref-package or the like you may need
      % to add the restoring of the values of some more 
      % referencing-properties here.
      \label{myEnvInstance.\myEnv@THISmyEnvCtr.LastmyCo}%
    \endgroup
  \fi
  \setcounter{myCoCtr}{\myEnv@SAVEDmyCoCtr}%
}%

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\footnotesize

\begin{myEnv}
  \myCo This is sentence 1. This is sentence 2.\myCo This is sentence 3.\myCo This is sentence 4. This is sentence 5. This is sentence 6.\myCo
\end{myEnv}

\bigskip

\bigskip

\noindent Now with nesting:

\bigskip

\begin{myEnv}
\noindent \verb|myEnv| -- nesting-level 0 -- nesting level 0 has \nolinkref{myEnv0last} \verb|\myCo|:\\
\myCo {}$\leftarrow$This number in parentheses comes from myEnv's nesting level 0's 1\textsuperscript{st} \verb|\myCo|.\\
\myCo {}$\leftarrow$This number in parentheses comes from myEnv's nesting level 0's 2\textsuperscript{nd} \verb|\myCo|.\\

  \begin{myEnv}
  \noindent \verb|myEnv| -- nesting-level 1 -- nesting level 1 has \nolinkref{myEnv1last} \verb|\myCo|:\\
  \myCo {}$\leftarrow$This number in parentheses comes from myEnv's nesting level 1's 1\textsuperscript{st} \verb|\myCo|.\\
  \myCo {}$\leftarrow$This number in parentheses comes from myEnv's nesting level 1's 2\textsuperscript{nd} \verb|\myCo|.\\

    \begin{myEnv}
    \noindent \verb|myEnv| -- nesting-level 2a -- nesting level 2a has \nolinkref{myEnv2alast} \verb|\myCo|:\\
    \myCo {}$\leftarrow$This number in parentheses comes from myEnv's nesting level 2a's 1\textsuperscript{st} \verb|\myCo|.\\
    \myCo {}$\leftarrow$This number in parentheses comes from myEnv's nesting level 2a's 2\textsuperscript{nd} \verb|\myCo|.\\
    \myCo {}$\leftarrow$This number in parentheses comes from myEnv's nesting level 2a's 3\textsuperscript{rd} \verb|\myCo|.\\
    \myCo {}$\leftarrow$This number in parentheses comes from myEnv's nesting level 2a's 4\textsuperscript{th} \verb|\myCo|.\\
    \myCo {}$\leftarrow$This number in parentheses comes from myEnv's nesting level 2a's 5\textsuperscript{th} \verb|\myCo|.\\
    \myCo {}$\leftarrow$This number in parentheses comes from myEnv's nesting level 2a's 6\textsuperscript{th} \verb|\myCo|.\\
    \myCo {}$\leftarrow$This number in parentheses comes from myEnv's nesting level 2a's 7\textsuperscript{th} \verb|\myCo|.\\
    \myCo {}\label{myEnv2alast}%
          $\leftarrow$This number in parentheses comes from myEnv's nesting level 2a's 8\textsuperscript{th} \verb|\myCo|.\\
    \end{myEnv}

  \noindent Back to \verb|myEnv| -- nesting-level 1 which has \nolinkref{myEnv1last} \verb|\myCo|:\\
  \myCo {}$\leftarrow$This number in parentheses comes from myEnv's nesting level 1's 3\textsuperscript{rd} \verb|\myCo|.\\
  \myCo {}$\leftarrow$This number in parentheses comes from myEnv's nesting level 1's 4\textsuperscript{th} \verb|\myCo|.\\

    \begin{myEnv}
    \noindent \verb|myEnv| -- nesting-level 2b -- nesting level 2b has \nolinkref{myEnv2blast} \verb|\myCo|:\\
    \myCo {}$\leftarrow$This number in parentheses comes from myEnv's nesting level 2b's 1\textsuperscript{st} \verb|\myCo|.\\
    \myCo {}$\leftarrow$This number in parentheses comes from myEnv's nesting level 2b's 2\textsuperscript{nd} \verb|\myCo|.\\
    \myCo {}\label{myEnv2blast}%
          $\leftarrow$This number in parentheses comes from myEnv's nesting level 2b's 3\textsuperscript{rd} \verb|\myCo|.\\
    \end{myEnv}

  \noindent Back to \verb|myEnv| -- nesting-level 1 which has \nolinkref{myEnv1last} \verb|\myCo|:\\
  \myCo {}$\leftarrow$This number in parentheses comes from myEnv's nesting level 1's 5\textsuperscript{th} \verb|\myCo|.\\
  \myCo {}\label{myEnv1last}%
        $\leftarrow$This number in parentheses comes from myEnv's nesting level 1's 6\textsuperscript{th} \verb|\myCo|.\\
  \end{myEnv}

\noindent Back to \verb|myEnv| -- nesting-level 0 which has \nolinkref{myEnv0last} \verb|\myCo|:\\
\myCo {}$\leftarrow$This number in parentheses comes from myEnv's nesting level 0's 3\textsuperscript{rd} \verb|\myCo|.\\
\myCo {}\label{myEnv0last}%
      $\leftarrow$This number in parentheses comes from myEnv's nesting level 0's 4\textsuperscript{th} \verb|\myCo|.\\
\end{myEnv}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If your environment's contents doesn't contain counter advancing commands, you can simply typeset the contents in a discarded box, changing the meaning of `\myCo` inside the box.

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\myCo}{}
 {
  \__bp_myco:
 }
\NewDocumentEnvironment{myEnv}{+b}
  {
   \int_zero:N \g__bp_myco_int
   \vbox_set:Nn \l_tmpa_box
    {
     \cs_set:Nn \__bp_myco: { \int_gincr:N \g__bp_myco_int }
     #1
    }
   #1
  }{}

\int_new:N \g__bp_myco_int
\cs_new:Nn \__bp_myco:
 {
  (\int_to_arabic:n { \g__bp_myco_int })
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{myEnv}
\myCo\ This is sentence 1. 
This is sentence 2. \myCo\ This is sentence 3. \myCo\ This is sentence 4. 
This is sentence 5. This is sentence 6.\myCo
\end{myEnv}

\end{document}
```

[image]